# How to get client id in salesforce rest api callout

Tags: rest

I am new to API calls, I would like to understand if it is possible to get Client ID through API call of the third party app to which I want to make a callout. I am trying to callout fitbit from salesforce and get statistics. I am thinking of getting client id and client secret using http request, when I know the name of the app created at Fitbit end. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Just came across this comment to a similar question - "The internal Id of the custom object definition is not exposed anywhere in the API", looks like object's Id cannot be accessed through the API.